# Pandas column has multiple values through multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, sorting

I have this sample dataset from a csv file.

| Year | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| 1894 | Romance |
| 1906 | Biography, Crime, Drama |
| 1911 | Drama |
| 1912 | Drama, History |
| 1911 | Adventure, Drama, Fantasy |
| 1912 | Biography, Drama |
| 1919 | Biography, Drama, Romance |

Using Pandas, I'd like to count the total occurence of a particular genre. As you can see, "Drama" appears in 6 rows, but some rows have other genres included.

This is what I have currently:

df[['Year','Genre']].query("genre == 'Drama'")

and it only returns

| Year | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| 1911 | Drama |

whereas I need it to return all the years that have "Drama", like so

| Year | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| 1911 | Drama |
| 1912 | Drama, History |
| 1911 | Adventure, Drama, Fantasy |
| 1912 | Biography, Drama |
| 1919 | Biography, Drama, Romance |

More specifically, I'd like to count how many times "Drama" appears throughout the dataset, despite certain columns having multiple values separated by comma. How can I go about doing so?

Comment: try `df['Genre'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()`

Answer (score 2):

```py
drama = df[df["Genre"].str.contains("Drama")]

print(len(drama))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str` methods which are "vectorised" and then simply sum to get the total number of entries that contain `"Drama"`:

`sum(df["Genre"].str.contains("Drama"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count Dramas, this should do it:

```
df[['Year','Genre']].query(
    "genre.str.contains('Drama').count()", engine="python")
```